# Is it possible to create a CSS selector like `parent[data-selected="$val1"] > child[data-id="$val1"]`?

Tags: css

I have the following HTML.

```html
<ul data-selected="foo">
    <li data-id="foo">text</li>
    <li data-id="bar">text</li>
    <li data-id="baz">text</li>
</ul>
```

And the following CSS.

```css
ul[data-selected="foo"] li[data-id="foo"],
ul[data-selected="bar"] li[data-id="bar"],
ul[data-selected="baz"] li[data-id="baz"]
{
    color: red;
}
```

`foo` in this example is an infinite number of dynamic values.

Is it possible to reduce this to one pure CSS selector (without JS continuously rewriting it)?

Something like:

```css
ul[data-selected="$val1"] li[data-id="$val1"]
```

It's for a closed system so experimental CSS is fine.

Comment: for example above you just need `ul[data-selected] li[data-id]{color: red}` if it more complex describe more in your question.

Comment: not, it's not possible

Comment: @uingtea, `ul[data-selected] li[data-id]{color: red}` would make all the list items red. I only want the list item whose `data-id` matches the unordered list's `data-selected` to be red.

Comment: You could use :has() https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/:has but it's only supported in Safari.

Comment: @Oste, how would you use `:has` to achieve this? It seems like a selector for the list rather than the list items.